# (C++ Error: pointer being freed was not allocated) for linked lists

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, queue, copy-constructor

With this main:

```
void print_first(Queue q);

int main()
{
   Queue q1;
   Queue q2(4);
   q2.push(5);
   q2.push(3);
//   q2.print_list();
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
      print_first(q2);
   }
   return 0;
}

void print_first(Queue q)
{
   if (!q.isEmpty())
   {
      cout << q.pop() << endl;
   }
   else
   {
       cout << "Nothing in queue" << endl;
   }
}
```

and these function definitions in a class Queue which has a linked lists with "head" and "tail" as pointers to the first and last Nodes in a linked list, each node which contains another struct "data" which stores an redefined type ElementType:

```
bool Queue::push(ElementType newElement)
{
   tail->next = new Node;
   if (tail->next == NULL)
   {
      return false;
   }
   tail->next->data.value = newElement;
   tail->next->next = NULL;
   tail = tail->next;
   return true;
}

ElementType Queue::pop()
{
   Node *newNode;
   ElementType returnData;
   returnData = head->data.value;
   newNode = head;
   head = head->next;
   delete newNode;
   return returnData;
}

bool Queue::isEmpty()
{
   if(head == NULL)
   {
       return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

why am I getting this error?
4
Assembly Line Simulator(9701) malloc: *** error for object 0x1001000e0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Comment: Did you follow the Rule of Three?

Comment: Change `void print_first(Queue q)` to `void print_first(Queue& q)` (in both places) and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the code you showed I think that the problem is that you pass a copy of the queue `q` to function `print_first`.

```
void print_first(Queue q)
```

If you did not write correctly the copy constructor then you can have some problems with the function.